# how to know returned value of prepare function in pdo in php

Tags: php, pdo

I am using pdo to insert some data in database in php and I wanna make sure everything is ok ?
for Example how i know name and family inserted in table?

```
$query="INSERT INTO `table`(`name`, `family`) VALUES (:fname ,:lname)";
    $statement=$conncection->prepare($query);
    $statement->bindParam(':fname',$_POST['name']);
    $statement->bindParam(':lname',$_POST['family']);
    $result=$statement->execute();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have the name and family that you are about to insert in the $_POST array. 
What you need to do is first check if the values of the post array are ok as per your requirements and then use a try catch block before you insert your values etc, This will be safer.

i.e.

```
 if(!empty($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['family']))
 {
     try
     {
         $query="INSERT INTO `table`(`name`, `family`) VALUES (:fname ,:lname)";
         $statement=$conncection->prepare($query);
         $statement->bindParam(':fname',$_POST['name']);
         $statement->bindParam(':lname',$_POST['family']);
         $statement->execute();
         $id=$connection->lastInsertId();

         //Use the ID if you need it here another query etc.

     }
     catch (PDOException $e)
     {
        //Write your code to handle the exception here
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You would use [`rowCount()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) to get the number of affected rows when doing `UPDATE`, `INSERT` or `DELETE`.

```
$affectedRows = $result->rowCount();
```